# why cloud firestore permission denied error occures?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I used Firebase service as a backend in my app.I strengthen security rules of my app.After doing it when I log out from app I encounter a problem like that. I share my debug concole with you:

```
Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /OnBoarding
[GETX] REMOVING ROUTE /HomePageScreen
W/Firestore(10626): (24.4.5) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(tales order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (10626): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
E/flutter (10626): #0      EventChannelExtension.receiveGuardedBroadcastStream
exception.dart:67
E/flutter (10626): #1      MethodChannelQuery.snapshots.<anonymous closure>
method_channel_query.dart:155
E/flutter (10626): <asynchronous suspension>
```

[image: here my firestore collections]
I have applied all rules to this collections.

It is my firestore rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
    }
    
    match /tales/{taleId}{
      allow read: if request.auth!=null;
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Why this error occures?

In my opinion there is no relation between my collections and logging out.Help me please.

Comment: Your rules clearly state that the user must be signed in to be able to query the tales collection.